# Click on TextField after wrapping it in GestureDetector doesn't work

Tags: flutter, click, textfield, gesturedetector, textformfield

Before wrapping in GestureDetector, Click/Tap/Selection on TextField/TextFormField works fine: can click and cursor is set where i click. Selection works normally.
After wrapping with GestureDetector, selection and click work still normally. The problem appears when I try to handle the “doubleTap”. At this point, the click and selection of the TextField works only the first time. With first time I mean that I have the TextField on a separate page so it works only the first time I enter the page; in order to be able to click and select again, I have to leave the page and return. The doubleTap is recognized correctly when I double tap.

I am on Windows 10 Pro Version 22H2.
I am using the current latest version of flutter on the stable channel: 3.10.5. I also tested on beta and master but problems still persisted.
I tested on web abb in Chrome and on mobile on Android version 13.

I saw on github a similar problem: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/122141
The problem is marked as solved but I still have it.

I noticed that the first time the gestures enter the arena, they are all present:
[image]

From the second time onward, only the DoubleTapGesture enters:
[image]

During some more tests, I noticed that at one point the TapAndPanGesture was winning but nothing was still happening; I think I was on the beta channel

Answer (score 1):

The temporary solution I found was to downgrade to flutter 3.7.3. I will try to update the answer if I notice in future versions that the problem is solved